# inputting var into an insert using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using python 2.7 and postgresql 10.0.

For learning purposes I am attempting to get user raw_input and place into an insert execute, but no matter what I do, either it be %s or {} and using .format i am receiving errors.
all values are string except age (int)

specifically

```
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO people(person_first, person_last, person_email, 
            person_age) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})".format(person_first, person_last, 
            person_email, person_age))
```

gives me non-string values (from the inputs)

and %s method gives me an error at the first '%' VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)

also have attempted VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) and also unsuccessful similar to %s

Comment: See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html It gives an example INSERT with placeholder values.

Comment: shouldn't you include the execution semicolon? And try single quote like
.. VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}') ; ".format(etc

Answer (score 0):

The code, as pasted, looks wrong. You have `with conn` and `c.execute`. Assuming `c` is the cursor, and `conn` is the connection, the way to use them would look like this: `with conn.cursor() as c:`. The cursor is a context manager that will properly clean itself up when the `with` block exits.

Also, don't get in the habit of using `.format()` on your SQL. That will 1) be a vector for SQL injection vulnerabilities and 2) it will break if the input contains a single quote character.

So, combining those two points, your code should look like this:

```
with conn.cursor() as c:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO people(person_first, person_last, person_email, 
        person_age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (person_first, person_last, 
        person_email, person_age,))
```

Note that the parameters are passed as a tuple directly to `execute`; the driver will parse the query, translate to appropriate SQL/parameter for the server, manage quoting, etc. If you are still seeing errors, post the traceback.

See also -

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Hope this helps.